Does anyone know the purpose of the .conversations folder in the Databricks workspace?
Databricks is creating a .conversations folder in users workspace folders with empty notebooks. Does anyone know why ? This happens when someone runs pyspark notebooks on a shared all purpose cluster.
I couldn't find anything about this in the Databricks documentation. I searched the spark docs too.

